# Custom button in Edit form that displays result

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am fairly new to .NET and MVC3 - and even Ajax and Json, and am working on an MVC3 (razor) application, using jqGrid, and so far it is immense(jqgrid that is!) and has dealt with everything I have thrown at it.
However, I have One Outstanding peice of functionality that I do not know How to accomplish.

Within the Edit form of a Row, I have Placed a Custom button called 'Reset Password'. I need the Onclick Event to call a piece of functionality in my Controller to go through some logic, generate a Password, and Return the new Password to the Screen.

Can anyone tell me How can I achieve this?

May thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a partial view result or json data from the action.

See the partial view approach [here](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/asp-net-mvc-partial-view-and-ajax-real-world-example/)